# Registration Function using ajax

Tags: ajax

I am using a plugin which does the frontend login in this way

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ppw_ajax_login', array($this, 'ajax_login'));

function ajax_login( ) {

header("Content-type: application/json");
$user = wp_signon( );

if ( !is_wp_error($user) ) {
    $reveal = 0;
    if ( get_user_meta( $user->ID, "ppw_subscribe", true) != '' OR $this->is_authorised() )
        $reveal = 1;

    die(json_encode(array(
        "status" => 1,
        "user_id"=>$user->ID,
        "reveal"=>$reveal
    )));
}
die(json_encode(array(
        "status" => 0,
        "error" => $user->get_error_message()
    )));
}
```

Now my question is how can I create a registration function in same manner?

I am trying to integrate the registration function with a paywall plugin. And so I want a custom code for AJAX registration.

Any help would be Great.

Comment: try http://wordpress.org/plugins/login-with-ajax/

Comment: I am trying to integrate the registration function with a paywall plugin. And so I want a custom code for AJAX registration.

Any help would be Great.